# (Ecto.QueryError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/association.ex:399: field `App.Location.post_id` in `where` does not exist in the schema in query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two models: Location and Post.

```
# Models
schema "locations" do
  ...
  has_many :posts, App.Post
  timestamps()
end

schema "posts" do
  ...
  has_one :location, App.Location
end
```

I'm able to successfully make insertions

```
changeset =
  location
  |> build_assoc(:posts)
  |> Post.changeset(params)
Repo.insert(changeset)
```

However when I try to load the data with `Repo.preload` I get an error

```
App.Repo.one(App.Post) |> App.Repo.preload(:location)
** (Ecto.QueryError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/association.ex:399: field `App.Location.post_id` in `where` does not exist in the schema in query:

from l in App.Location,
  where: l.post_id == ^5,
  select: {l.post_id, l}
```

Comment: Have you added the association in the Ecto Schema?

Comment: @Dogbert Give me one minute. Stackoverflow submited the post when I was adding tags and pressed enter...

Comment: I have `add :location_id, references(:locations, on_delete: :nothing)` in posts migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a foreign key for another table in a table, the relationship you need to use is `belongs_to`, not `has_one`. This should work:

```
schema "posts" do
  ...
  belongs_to :location, App.Location
end
```

Comment: I guess I should review my database design. Thank you for the help!